# Looping Througn an Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, nested-loops

I have the following array named $entries:

```
array ( 
  0 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8132, 'racer_id' => 1302, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  1 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8239, 'racer_id' => 851, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  2 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8240, 'racer_id' => 850, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  3 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8241, 'racer_id' => 1222, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  4 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8243, 'racer_id' => 1221, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  5 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8250, 'racer_id' => 673, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  6 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8255, 'racer_id' => 674, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  7 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8258, 'racer_id' => 666, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
  8 => array ( 'entry_id' => 8266, 'racer_id' => 193, 'class_id' => 20, ), 
)
```

and this code to loop thru that array.

```
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $list[0]['heat_count']; ++$i) {
       if ($entry['class_id'] == $class) {
           $heats[$class] = [
               'heat_nbr'   => $i,
               'entry_id'   => $entry['entry_id'],
               'racer_name' => $f->getRacerFullName($entry['racer_id'])
           ];
       }
    }
}
```

I am not getting the output I need. The variable $list[0]['heat_count'] comes from an earlier query that counts the amount of riders in the "heat".

What I need is to set the "heat_number" according to the "heat_count", so if there are 2 heats, I need to iterate thru the $entries array and take the 1st to heat 1 and the second to heat 2 and so on thru the loop. If the "heat_count" is 3, then 1st to 1, 2nd to 2, 3rd to 3, 4th to 1, 5th to 2 6th to 3.. and so on.

There can be any number of heats per class in an event from 1 to 50. So hard coding that is impossible without a million if statements.

Can anyone understand what I'm getting at here and push me in the right direction?

This is what I get from the above loop now:

```
array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8132) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8239) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8240) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8241) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8243) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8250) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8255) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8258) } array(2) { ["heat_nbr"]=> int(2) ["entry_id"]=> int(8266) }
```

Comment: So you have a list of entrants and you are trying to divide them up between the different heats?

Comment: it should be good to show us the structure of `$list` and the result you expect

Comment: Yes. but a simple divide doesn't fly. I need to place them in heats based on signup. 

1st to heat 1, 2nd to heat 2 and so on..

Comment: @olibiaz, the structure of $list isn't really relevant to this loop. Just know that the value of that variable changes based on the count of $entries

Comment: so if you have 12 entrants and 3 heats, it would you want them to be divided like:

[heat 1] > 1,4,7,10
[heat 2] > 2,5,8,11
[heat 3] > 3,6,9,12

Comment: Yes, pretty much dead on..

Comment: So you have a condition in there if the class matches, so you aren't assigning entrants when the class doesn't match, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what that is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of how many entrants you have assigned to the heats, so you can assign the next heat number.

Something like this should work:

```
$numberOfHeats = $list[0]['heat_count'];
$counter = 0;

foreach ($entries as $entry){
    if($entry['class_id'] == $class) {

        $nextHeatNumberToAssign = ($counter % $numberOfHeats) + 1;
        $counter++;

        $heats[$class][] = [
            'heat_nbr'   => $nextHeatNumberToAssign,
            'entry_id'   => $entry['entry_id'],
            'racer_name' => $f->getRacerFullName($entry['racer_id'])
            ];
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly.. after I set $counter = 1; outside the main loop that is. ;)

Comment: oh, excellent... good to hear..!  I updated it in the code above.. :-)

Comment: I started with a counter of 1, as there will never be a heat 0 and then added the a +1 to the end of 'heat_nbr'   => $nextHeatNumberToAssign, as that wasn't incrementing correctly

Comment: I set it to 0 outside the loop because the first thing it does inside the loop is increment, so the first one would get assigned the value of 1.  But, now looking at it, I think we need to add a '+ 1'  after the `$counter % $numberOfHeats;` to make it 1 based instead of 0-based.

Comment: It works great, however, I noticed that one heat race in my test data gets incremented incorrectly. It's starts with heat 2...

Comment: try as I have it above now.

Comment: Thats even worse.. everything heat assigns the first rider to the last heat and then goes back to the correct order.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115572/discussion-between-bizzybob-and-indymx).